# Зубчатые массивы и LINQ

Tags: c#, массивы, linq

Задание:
 В каждой нечетной строке ступенчатой матрице найти произведение элементов. Выбрать отрицательные и посчитать их количество, если отрицательных нет вывести -1.
Допустим есть массив:

```
int[][] numbers = new int[3][];
numbers[0] = new int[] { 3, 2 };
numbers[1] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
numbers[2] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Например я хочу проверить все ли элементы больше нуля
Вот код для одномерных массивов:

```
if (numbers.All(x => x > 0))
    Console.WriteLine("Все элементы больше нуля");
```

Как будет выглядеть код для ступенчатых массивов? И как к ним правильно обращаться?

Comment: На будущее, если ваш вопрос был закрыт со статусом [требует правки], нужно вносить исправления в вопрос, а не задавать новый. Для редактирования вопроса/ответа, под ним предусмотрена кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1034155/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В каждой нечетной строке ступенчатой матрице найти произведение элементов.

   ```
   int[] result = (numbers.Select(x => Array.IndexOf(numbers, x) % 2 != 0
       ? x.Aggregate((first, item) => first * item) : -1))
       .Where(x => x != -1)
       .ToArray();
   ```

   Вывод: 6.
2. Выбрать отрицательные и посчитать их количество, если отрицательных нет вывести -1.

   ```
   int answer = numbers.Sum(x => x.Count(y => y > 0)) == numbers.Sum(x => x.Count())
       ? -1 : numbers.Sum(x => x.Count(y => y < 0));
   ```

   Вывод: -1 по вашему примеру
3. Для ступенчатого массива

   ```
   if (numbers.All(x => x.All(y => y > 0))
   ```

Comment: Я исправил форматирование. Теперь синтаксис подсвечивается. Но если вы несогласны с правкой, считаете, что так смотрится хуже, напишите - откатим правку.

Comment: А что означает строчка numbers.Sum(x => x.Count() ?

Comment: @ИльяЧеркасов Количество всех цифр, для сравнения) Если количество положительный чисел совпадает с количеством чисел в массиве , то -1

Answer (score 0):

Как-то непривычно использовать для подобных задач LiNQ, но должен признать, что получилось немного более читабельно, чем на обычных циклах, правда на счет производительности не уверен, для олимпиад и задач критичных ко времени выполнения применять бы не стал, но разница должна быть невелика на малом объеме данных, особенно с учетом низкой скорости вывода в консоль.

```
numbers
    .Where((row, idx) => idx % 2 == 0)//выбираем нечетные строки в естественном порядке (четные индексы)
    .Select(row =>//собираем результат из данных строки
         row.Any(x => x < 0)//если хоть один элемент меньше 0
         ? row.Aggregate((x,y) => x * y)//берем произведение
         : -1)//иначе -1
    .ToList()//для следующей операции получаем List<int>
    .ForEach(val => Console.WriteLine(val));
```

Если подключить NuGET-пакет MoreLINQ или самостоятельно дописать метод-расширение ForEach для `IEnumerable<T>` (штатно он предусмотрен только для `List<T>`), то можно избавиться от `ToList()`, что позволит использовать немного меньше памяти и чуть-чуть улучшить производительность за счет отсутствия выделения памяти под List и заполнение его данными:

```
numbers
    .Where((row, idx) => idx % 2 == 0)//выбираем нечетные строки в естественном порядке (четные индексы)
    .Select(row =>//собираем результат из данных строки
         row.Any(x => x < 0)//если хоть один элемент меньше 0
         ? row.Aggregate((x,y) => x * y)//берем произведение
         : -1)//иначе -1
    .ForEach(val => Console.WriteLine(val));
```

Comment: Я таки дико извиняюсь, но разве ТС нужно не **количество** элементов?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov думал на эту тему, но т.к. это одно задание, то видимо все таки нет. Но гадать не хочется, как понял так и ответил, поправить - минутное дело =) Вообще меня давно интересует: авторы методичек тестируют свои творения перед массовой печатью или выплёвывают на студентов as is, мол "это их проблема, я свою галочку за подготовку методички получил"? Если бы сам ни когда не преподавал, может вопрос бы и не возник, но блин... прям бесят эти "авторитетные профессора" порой.

Comment: таки аналогичные мысли мне порой лезут в голову. Ко мне недавно обращался за помощью друг, который все прозябает в универе, ибо никак не мог выполнить простое, казалось бы, условие: методичка просила сгенерировать числа, по определённым правилам их преобразовать и вывести в консольку. Забава в том, что автор методички явно был незнаком с матчастью, ибо задание местами требовало возведение отрицательного числа в вещественную степень ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov угу, вот и я о том же. Если в естественно научных предметах все более-менее неплохо, хотя тоже попадаются перлы, то в около-IT полный мрак.